# Отправка формы при загрузке фото

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, html, php, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы форма отправлялась на сервер сразу после выбора фотографии пользователем?
Т.е. есть форма:

```
 <form action="album.php?action=<?php echo $results['formAction']?>" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" name="myform" id="myform">
     <ul>
       <li>
           <label for="img">Фотография подкаталога. </label>
          <input  type="file" name="img" id="img" />
       </li>
    </ul
 </form>
```

И мне нужно, что бы сразу же после загрузки пользователя перенаправляло бы на "album.php?action=<?php echo $results['formAction']?>", а данные из input отправлялись бы на сервер.
Вообщем как сделать, что выбор фотографии отрабатывал так же, как и нажатие sumbit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно стОит посмотреть в сторону [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com)?

Если нужен именно такой подход - попробуйте использовать **onchange** для отправки формы: